# Can every manifold be a complete manifold or a non-complete manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complete-spaces

Given a manifold M, does there exist riemmanian metrics such that M is a complete manifold?

Given a non-compact manifold M, does there exist riemmanian metrics such that M is not complete?

Comment: By whitney, if $\dim M=n$, then $M$ embeds as a closed subspace in $\Bbb R^{2n+1}$, and you can pull back the induced metric, which is complete, since the restriction of a complete metric to a closed subspace remains complete

Comment: Additionally, for the second claim you can use the same Whitney embedding and pull back a suitable incomplete metric in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ (such as the standard metric on the open unit disc).

Comment: Thanks. The proof of the first claim is good. But in the second claim, a closed subspace of a incomplete space could be complete, how to overcome this difficulty?

Comment: While I'm not sure of all the details, such an embedding (by noncompactness and the fact that the embedding is proper) contains a curve which "escapes to infinity", and, having chosen such a curve, there should be a metric which gives it a finite length.

Comment: Giving an idea for M= $\mathbb{R}^n$. Write down the geodesic equation for arbitrary metric. Turn it into first order 2n dimensional equation. It is flow of a vector field on  $\mathbb{R}^2n$  Find some vector field that does not have global flow and get connection coefficients than find metric giving these connection coefficient. Not sure if this would work. Rest is using hopf-rinow theorem to claim it is not complete since it is not geodesically complete.